# Django doesn't show the CSS of my template

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

The problem is described in title. I have this template for a blog that I'm creating using `Django`.

When I open it normally, using double click over the HTML file, it looks like this:

[image: The template Working]

But when I open it via url from the Django project, it looks like this

[image: Template doesnt works]

It only shows a green square (part of the css) but obviously can't open the css correctly.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Let's see your JS console

Answer (score 0):

In Django you don't open the HTML with double click on the file, you need to run the server first and open your site using the localhost (like you did in the second picture).

Judging by those images, are you sure you put the image in the static folder? In Django, the HTML files stays in the "templates" folder of your app and the css, javascript and images in the "static" folder.

If this answer doesn't help you, then you should post your code here, otherwise I can't find the problem.